# XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete

Tags: java, xml, http, payment-gateway, fiddler

We are using virtual merchant payment gateway in our application:

https://www.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/download/developerGuide.pdf

I am trying to record a CCSALE transaction but I keep getting this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn><errorCode>6042</errorCode><errorName>Invalid Request Format</errorName><errorMessage>XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete.</errorMessage></txn>
```

The XML I am passing in request in Fiddler POST is:

```
<txn>
<ssl_merchant_id>my_mer_id</ssl_merchant_id>
<ssl_user_id>my_usr_id</ssl_user_id>
<ssl_pin>my_pin</ssl_pin>
<ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode>
<ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type>
<ssl_card_number>4111111111111111</ssl_card_number>
<ssl_exp_date>1215</ssl_exp_date>
<ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount>
</txn>
```

I have simply removed my merchant id, user id and ssl pin. The rest of the information is just as it is. I am posting the data to: https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/processxml.do

Can anybody let me know why does it say XML is not well formed?

Comment: What did the support people for this web site say when you asked them?  They may see more detail in their logs than you can see.

Comment: You need to ask for the encoding type they are supporting.

Comment: Looking at page 77 of that document, it looks like your not including the tag <ssl_track_data>, which is required on a swipe, you may need one of the other tags <ssl_show_form> or <ssl_card_present> on a keyed entry.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks! But if you look page 47's sample it doesn't include such things. Further I don't know how will I get that information like track_data etc.

Comment: @Jack Have you tried adding the XML header?  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @Mike: Yes. That's a good point but I already tried that before posting on SO. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Jack time to call/email their support then...

Comment: @Mike: Yes :) I already emailed them. Will post it as answer as soon as I receive their response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, after hours of frustration I find PHP way of doing this very retarded. Since this XML error was so persistent, I wanted to try this in Coldfusion and in 2-3 minutes, the whole thing was done, no XML errors, no SSL crap returned from the API. Anyway, enough with the venting! This is probably what you need to prevent that XML well formedness super duper message :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("xmldata=" . $fields_string));
```

Assuming you are following their documentation and you are holding the variables in fields_string all you need to do is type something that mimics a variable for the API. In this case, xmldata will do.

I have yet to listen to the answer which throws this : `Curl error: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104`

This is thanks to listening to the errors, otherwise $result returned empty after I got rid of XML error. So, here it goes :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("xmldata=" . $fields_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
else
    echo 'the return is ' . $result;
```

SSL is not setup yet so why the heck they bothered with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST? It's not working even when it's false, this whole thing turned out Charlie Foxtrot!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error as well, here is my working curl function

```
    public function send_curl_xml($xml=NULL){

    $data = http_build_query(array("xmldata"=>$xml));

    $headers = array(
        "Accept: application/xml",
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        //,"Content-length: " . strlen($data)
    );

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //echo $response;

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        print curl_error($ch);
        return false;
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

$xml variable is DOCDocument object, be sure to use $xml->saveHTML() if you are dynamically generating your xml (The key here is to remove "" line in your xml string.)