# Why isn't my XML API request accepted by the API?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have been trying, for days, to send a simple XML request to an API. Even with the help of the tech support, absolutely nothing works. I still get an error telling me that my XML isn't well-formed or is invalid.

Here is my cURL request:

```
$data = array_merge([
            'ssl_transaction_type' => "$transactionType",
            'ssl_merchant_id' => $this->merchant_id,
            'ssl_user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'ssl_pin' => $this->pin
        ], $data);
        
        $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<txn/>');
        $data = array_flip($data);
        array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getXMLUrl());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ));     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array("xmldata=" . explode(PHP_EOL, $xml->asXML())[1])));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Why do I explode the XML? It's because I need to only get the part with the root, not the version, etc. according to the tech support.

I followed this: [XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158960/xml-request-is-not-well-formed-or-request-is-incomplete) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the answer using `http_build_query` of that link you show, looks like the array should be slightly different - `http_build_query(array("xmldata" => explode(PHP_EOL, $xml->asXML())[1]))`

Comment: If the previous comment doesn't work, just bake the actual expected XML into the document as a raw string and see if that works. If it does, your programming task will be to recreate that XML document and you can forget about the API for a bit.

Comment: @NigelRen It just tells me that I can't convert an array to a string.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Same thing, doesn't work...

Comment: Please show the outputted xml.

Comment: Are you able to provide any documentation to us regarding the API? Also, can you try passing `, '', '&'` as the second and third parameters to `http_build_query `